# Store data into cache memory using cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am new in python and cherrypy. I want to store data into cache memory using cherrypy.

Is there any simple and basic put, get and delete example?

Comment: Maybe this will help. Not exactly a sample but should point in the right direction. https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html?highlight=cherrypy.lib.caching#module-cherrypy.lib.caching

Comment: @electrometro Do you have sample code how to start with this? I just want one simple program which can implement get, put and clear method. Actually I don't have any idea how to start with that. I have go through the above link but bot able to start.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used cherrypy before so I am not familiar with the setup of their framework. However if you were using django I could show you how fairly easily. I am sure someone will come along that can help.

Comment: @electrometro It would be great if you share some example with django.

Comment: @electrometro Why you removed your answer? That's was also a great example. I am looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a simple dictionary as cache. Although you'd have to handle expiration yourself. Here is an example on how you could use `MemoryCache`. When you run this script, the page `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_cache` shows every 10 seconds different content. `MemoryCache.put` stores objects per similar request, which means different URI parameters are corresponding to different "bins". You can try it by switching between `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_cache?foo=0` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_cache?bar=42`.

```
import cherrypy
import datetime
import sys
from cherrypy.lib.caching import MemoryCache

cache = MemoryCache()
cache.delay = 10 # content auto-expires after 10 seconds

class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def test_cache(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = cache.get()
        if not data:
            obj = datetime.datetime.today()
            size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
            cache.put(obj, size)
            data = obj
        return 'obj: %s, id: %s' % (data, id(data))

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: I have another problem. How can I get data from cache using id?

Comment: Is data are store in RAM?

Comment: The caching happens actually in a simple dictionary, so yes: the cache is in the RAM. If you restart cherrypy, your cache is cleared. I'm not entirely sure what you mean with 'get data by id'. The keys of this dictionary are generated as `uri = cherrypy.url(qs=request.query_string)`. If you need to bypass the logic of MemoryCache, you can access this dict directly as `cache.store`. For further investigation I recommend reading the source at: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/b24b9f2f7ab10f0c8f6dba4eee1fc078b4ddcf8f/cherrypy/lib/caching.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default